# I keep getting the error, "Unimplemented substep definition" in IntelliJ with Cucumber?

Tags: cucumber, intellij-idea-2016

I have already:

- Downloaded the `Cucumber Java`, `Gherkin plugin`
- I already have `the steps` and `features` directories:

My directory structure looks like this:

```
- test
    - java
        - features
            - featureSet1
                - oneFeature.feature
                - anotherFeature.feature
            - featuresSet2
                - twoFeature.feature
            - CucumberTests.java
        - steps
                - step1.java
                - step2.java
```

Under the features folder, I have a file called, `CucumberTests.java`. I'm able to run the tests via `mvn test` but the red error marks reallllly annoy me.

I have these tags in `CucumberTest.java`, which is supposed to run the tests:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/surefire-
    reports/cucumber", "json:target/surefire-
    reports/cucumberOriginal.json"},
             features = {"src/test/java/features/featuresSet1",
                         "src/test/java/features/featuresSet2",
                         },
             tags = {"~@ignore"},
             glue = {"steps"})
```

Comment: The issue might be from a plugin called `Substeps IntelliJ Plugin`. Search for it and uninstall. `Cucumber for Java` and `Gherkin` should be enough.

Comment: Hey, you're right. Thanks!

Comment: Added an answer as it seems more people were interested in this.

Comment: Need to disable Substeps plugin or uninstall Substeps plugin if already installed in settings--> plugin then the error “Unimplemented substep definition” wont occur in IntelliJ with Cucumber?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

The issue is from `Substeps IntelliJ Plugin` that `IntelliJ` suggests you install when it locates a `.feature` file inside your project.

[image]

Just ignore this extension when it pops up or uninstall if you already have it.

`Cucumber for Java` and `Gherkin` should be enough.

Comment: How to installed plugin from IDEA https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/installing-updating-and-uninstalling-repository-plugins.html#uninstall

Comment: I uninstalled Substeps IntelliJ Plugin then it works great ! thanks :)

Comment: I wasted an hour figuring out issue.